# Toast Notifications showing mixed user profile pictures for Outlook emails

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-teams, action-center

We recently upgraded to Windows 10 last week at our company. Since then a growing number of our users have reported showing the wrong persons profile picture for an email or Teams message on toast notifications. This seems to be temporarily corrected by clearing the ActionCenterCache folder, however we were hoping for a more long term solution/fix.

This issue does not seem to be limited to internal users as outside emails have gotten internal users profile pictures, none of the users I have checked so far even have a local contacts list as a possible cause.

Comment: Try Disk Cleanup and ensure that Thumbnails is selected.

Comment: These incorrect profile pictures are for themselves or other users within the AD domain? I would try clearing out the Outlook profiles for one of these users, allowing them to recreate their profile, and see if the problem resurfaces.  I would typically blame this on the GAL.  I cannot think of a single reason the upgrade to Windows 10 would have affect a Outlook profile picture or users outside of your domain (or even inside your domain) which points me to something else changing.

Comment: Agree with Ramhound. Recreating their profile may be a methods to check if there're something wrong with the datafile or the profile itself. In addition, i noticed that both the notification of Outlook and Teams would display the wrong profile picture, considering the impact of the damage Outlook program itself, It is recommended that you could try to uninstall and reinstall Office(https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) or fix the Office application to check whether the problem still exists.

Comment: Hi @NickPomroy , I am writing to see if there is any progress on the issue. If you have any questions or need further help on this, feel free to post back.